# Excel cell's row number as a function of other cell's values

Tags: excel

I don't use Excel very often. I have `D3=C3-L(600+B3*200)` in my program which doesn't work. I would like to assign this expression the meaning of "D3 equals sum of C3 and the cell in column L with the row number (600+B3*200)". (B3*200 being natural is accounted for in my Excel program). Which functions should i employ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd), with `L:L` as the *array* and `600+B3*200` as the *row_num*:

```
=D3=C3-INDEX(L:L,600+B3*200)
```

Comment: i  copy-pasted = it and Excel says "it's not a function". It is probably a simple semantic error but i'm too clueless to fidn it myself. all cells in this expression have number format

Comment: INDEX is a function. Are you not in an English install of Excel?

Comment: oh, im using russian excel. okay, ill try to adapt things into my version myself then from here, thank you for the help !

Answer (score 0):

```
=C3+INDEX(L:L,600+(B3*200),1))
```

Index returns the value of a given reference intersection.

Comment: Note - the outer SUM is redundant.